# How to send an HTML5 sqlite result set to a server via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, sqlite, html

Suppose I'm getting a result set like so:

```
db.transaction( 
    function(transaction) { transaction.executeSql( 
    'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table;',
     [],function(transaction, result){

     //package the result in here somehow to send to the server via AJAX

},errorHandler);
```

I'm looking for the specific code (as opposed to say "serialize the result") for the best way to 'package' the result to be send via AJAX to a server. A JQuery solution is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a common solution for serializing in JS:

```
JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: This will work with each individual row as `var row = result.rows.item(i); JSON.stringify(row)` but not directly as `JSON.stringify(result)`. Having stringified each row separately, how should I go about combining them into a single JSON object?

Comment: You can put all the rows to the regular array and then serialize this array.

Comment: If I do something like `resultSet[i] = JSON.stringify(row);` in the loop then `console.log(resultSet);' returns `["{"id":1}", "{"id":2}"]`. Can I send this form directly via AJAX?

Comment: I can, but it'll be hard to parse this data on server. I would recommend you to `resultSet[i] = row` in loop and then `JSON.stringify(resultSet)`. Tnen on server you can just `JSON.parse(data)`.